# Procedures MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Olá, sou novo em procedures e estou com uma dúvida que não encontrei na internet.

Estou precisando criar um procedimento de inclusão de 2 tabelas: "Usuario", "Fornecedor".

O fornecedor tem uma FK de usuário, ou seja, nessa procedure, eu preciso inserir um usuario, obter o id desse usuario e inserir um fornecedor com a Fk do usuario que foi criado.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Agradeço desde já...

Comment: Você já sabe como declarar um procedure? Se sim, seria interessante postar o que já conseguiu fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após inserir o usuário, utilize `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` para obter o `id` do usuário criado, armazene o `id` em uma variável e, então, insira o fornecedor.

Comment: OOh legal! Desse jeito deve funcionar sim! Mas ai me surgiu outra dúvida! Essa é a maneira correta de fazer?

Comment: Sempre que um usuário for cadastrado, é necessário que seja também cadastrado um fornecedor relacionado? Se sim, talvez a melhor opção seja um trigger no `AFTER INSERT`.